# HTML button not working with my javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am creating a button operated set of traffic lights, 
i have this HTML and JAVASCRIPT

```js
var lightStates = {
  red: 0,
  amber: 1,
  green: 2
};
var currentState = lightStates.red;

document.getElementById('changeBtn').onclick = function() {
  changeState();
};


function changeState() {
  clear();
  switch (currentState) {
    case lightStates.red:
      {
        document.getElementById("red").className = "light red";
        currentState = lightStates.amber;
      }
      break;
    case lightStates.amber:
      {
        document.getElementById("amber").className = "light amber";
        currentState = lightStates.green;
      }
      break;
    case lightStates.green:
      {
        document.getElementById("green").className = "light green";
        currentState = lightStates.red;
      }
      break;
  }
}

function clear() {
  document.getElementById("red").className = "light off";
  document.getElementById("amber").className = "light off";
  document.getElementById("green").className = "light off";
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src=javasript.js></script>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<div class="traffic-light">
  <div class="light off" id="red"></div>
  <div class="light off" id="amber"></div>
  <div class="light off" id="green"></div>
</div>
<button id="changeBtn">Change</button>
<input type="button" id="changeBtn" onclick="changestate" </input>

</html>
```

and the lights on a css sheet, 
the problem I am having is that when i run the code in a browser, the button does not do anything at all, what am i getting wrong?

Comment: convert onclick="changestate" to onClick="changestate()"

Comment: Check this link:-https://codedump.io/share/6BubpXSG1rX/1/traffic-light-with-button-and-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're trying to invoke the function in two separate ways, both inline and as an event handler.
2. The markup is invalid, both with typos and with multiple identical `id` values.
3. The event handler is being assigned before the element actually exists.

Remove the duplicate button and the inline `onclick` and include the JavaScript *after* the element(s):

```
<input type="button" id="changeBtn"></input>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javasript.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you so much, i can see the logic now and it is working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

remove this part of your html code

`<button id="changeBtn">Change</button>
<input type="button" id="changeBtn" onclick="changestate"</input>`

Change it to this.

`<button id="changeBtn" onclick="changestate()">Change</button>`

I believe your issues are coming from not having a closing `>` on your input, not having () on your onclick call & having two elements with the same id.